# elasticsearch averaging a field on a bucket

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a newbie to elasticsearch, trying to understand how aggregates and metrics work.  I was particularly running an aggregate query to retrieve average num of bytesOut based on clientIPHash from an elasticsearch instance.  The query I created (using kibana) is as follows:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1476177616965,
                  "lte": 1481361616965,
                  "format": "epoch_millis"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ClientIP_Hash",
        "size": 50,
        "order": {
          "1": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "Bytes Out"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It gives me some output (supposed to be avg) grouped on clientIPHash like below:

```
ClientIP_Hash: Descending   Average Bytes Out 
64e6b1f6447fd044c5368740c3018f49    1,302,210
4ff8598a995e5fa6930889b8751708df    94,038
33b559ac9299151d881fec7508e2d943    68,527
c2095c87a0e2f254e8a37f937a68a2c0    67,083
...
```

The problem is, if I replace the avg with sum or min or any other metric type, I still get same values.

```
ClientIP_Hash: Descending   Sum of Bytes Out 
64e6b1f6447fd044c5368740c3018f49    1,302,210
4ff8598a995e5fa6930889b8751708df    94,038
33b559ac9299151d881fec7508e2d943    68,527
c2095c87a0e2f254e8a37f937a68a2c0    67,083
```

I checked the query generated by kibana, and it seems to correctly put the keyword 'sum' or 'avg' accordingly.  I am puzzled why I get the same values for avg and sum or any other metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you see if the sample data set of yours have more values. As min, max and Avg remains the same if you have only one value.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. After examining the data, I found that data  only one record per cientIPHash, except for one single clientIP which had 10.